# Confusion with trace of gamma matrices

Tags: dirac-matrices, trace, clifford-algebra

Using $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu} \mathbf{1}$, it is easy to show that:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu = 4\eta^{\mu\nu}
\end{align*}
Now, it is also true that $(\gamma^\rho)^4 = \mathbf{1} \ \ \forall \rho \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Choosing $\rho \neq \mu,\nu$, one can derive:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu &= \operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho (\gamma^\rho)^3\\
&= -\operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\rho \gamma^\nu (\gamma^\rho)^3 \\
&= -\operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho (\gamma^\rho)^3 \\
&= -\operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \\
\implies \operatorname{tr} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu &= 0
\end{align*}
where in the penultimate step I used the cyclicity of the trace.

For $\mu = \nu$, this is a contradiction. I am sure there is an easy solution to my confusion, I am baffled that I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ABCD\rightarrow ACBD$ is not a cyclic permutation and it does not leave the trace invariant. We have 
$$\mathrm{Tr}(ABCD)= \mathrm{Tr}(DABC)=\mathrm{Tr}(CDAB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BCDA)$$